# Legendre symbol, product of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So, it's the question:
[image]

I solve it by assuming $d$ is a prime number.

My question is: Why I can assume that?

I wrote $d$ as a product of primes ($d$=$p_1$$p_2$...$p_r$), therefore $(\frac{d}{p})$ = $\prod_{i=1}^r$ $(\frac{p_i}{p})$.  How to continue?

Thanks

Comment: We can assume $d$ is prime because if it was not, then we can write it as a product of primes, say $d=ab$, and so $a|m$ and $b|m$, and the Legendre symbol is multiplicative, as you pointed out.

Comment: a|m and b|m? I think it should be or. I still don't get it

Comment: No, because if $a$ and $b$ are factors of $d$, and $d$ is a factor of $m$, we conclude that, by unique factorization, $a$ and $b$ must be factors of $m$.

Comment: Oh, of course. But still, where is the contradiction? why d isn't a product of primes?

Comment: There is no contradiction; you just eliminate the case of $d$ being composite because we *could* break it down into primes, and then do each case. So if $d=abc$, then we could just show each case for $a, b,$ and $c$. I'm working on your problem now but I'm usually pretty slow, so someone will probably beat me to it :)

Comment: take your time :) thanks!

Comment: By the way, this problem becomes even easier if one uses Jacobi's extension of the Legendre symbol: for example, if $d$ is odd and positive, then one can simply write $(\frac dp)=(\frac pd)=(\frac1d)=1$, since $p\equiv1\pmod d$.

Comment: right, but as you mentioned, only if d is odd and positive.

Comment: Well, from what I'm familiar with, $d$ prime means that $d$ is positive. That's what we did when *I* took number theory; it might have been different for others though.

Comment: and if p and d are coprime

Comment: $p$ and $d$ are coprime because they are *both* prime :)

Comment: again, in the case that d is prime. But if it isn't?

Comment: We can assume $d$ will be prime, for if it was not, then we could write $d=p_{1}^{a_1}p_{2}^{a_2}...p_{r}^{a_r}$ and then perform the proof for *each* $p_{k}^{a_1}$, making use of the fact that $(\frac{p_{k}^{a_k}}{p}) = (\frac{p_k p_k ... p_k}{p})= (\frac{p_{k}}{p})(\frac{p_{k}}{p})...(\frac{p_{k}}{p})$

Comment: Oh, now I get it! thanks!

Comment: For odd prime divisors of $d$, the result follows by Reciprocity. For the possible prime divisor $2$ of $d$, the result follows from the fact $p$ is  then of the shape $8t+1$.

Comment: @MS93 I've fixed my answer...sorry about the mess :)

Answer (score 1):

We can assume $d$ is prime. If it wasn't, then write $d=(±1)2^a p_{1}^{a_1}p_{2}^{a_2}...p_{r}^{a_r}$, and so $(\frac{p_{k}^{a_k}}{p}) = (\frac{p_k p_k ... p_k}{p})= (\frac{p_{k}}{p})(\frac{p_{k}}{p})...(\frac{p_{k}}{p})$. We could consider the case for $d=(±1)$ or $d=2^a$ separately as well. So, without loss of generality, assume $d$ is prime:

1. $p=4m+1 \Rightarrow p≡1 \mod 4$ (since $4m=p-1 \Rightarrow 4|p-1 \Rightarrow p≡1 \mod 4$).
2. $d|m \Rightarrow kd=m$ for some integer $k$.
3. Quadratic reciprocity: $(\frac{p}{q})(\frac{q}{p}) = 1$ if $p≡1 \mod 4$ or $q≡1 \mod 4$.

Notice that $(\frac{d}{p})(\frac{p}{d})=1$ since $p≡1 \mod 4$. So either $(\frac{d}{p})$ and $(\frac{p}{d})$ are both $1$ or $-1$; i.e., $\color{blue}{(\frac{d}{p}) = (\frac{p}{d})}$.

Write $p=4m+1$, and so $p=4(kd) + 1 = (4k)d + 1$, so $(4k)d = p-1$, so $d|p-1$, so $p≡1 \mod d$ and so $1≡p \mod d$ (congruence modulo $n$ is reflexive).

Ask yourself: is $x^2 ≡ p \mod d$ solvable? Surely it is; $x=1$ is a solution! So $(\frac{p}{d}) = 1$. By quadratic reciprocity $(\frac{d}{p}) = (\frac{p}{d}) = 1$, so $(\frac{d}{p}) = 1$.